# Segmented Control Selected Index Always showing 0 In Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Plugin.Segmented control with my xamarin forms freshMVVM but it always through 0 Index.

Here is my XAML

```
 <control:SegmentedControl x:Name="SegmentedControl"            
                TintColor="BlueViolet"
                SelectedTextColor="White"  SelectedSegment="{Binding SelectedSegment}" 
                DisabledColor="Gray"  
                Margin="8,8,8,8">
                        <control:SegmentedControl.Children>
                            <control:SegmentedControlOption Text="Item1"/>
                            <control:SegmentedControlOption Text="Item2"/>
                            <control:SegmentedControlOption Text="Item3"/>
                        </control:SegmentedControl.Children>
                        <control:SegmentedControl.Behaviors>
                            <local:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="OnSegmentSelected" Command="{Binding SegIndexChanged}" />
                        </control:SegmentedControl.Behaviors>
                    </control:SegmentedControl>
```

My PageModel(Using FreshMVVM)

```
private int _selectedSegment;
        public int SelectedSegment
        {
            get { return _selectedSegment; }
            set
            {
                _selectedSegment = value;                
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSegment");
            }
        }
        public Command SegIndexChanged
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(() =>
                {
                    Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Message", "Selected Index is : " + SelectedSegment, "Ok");
                });
            }
        }
```

It always showing 0 Index. why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set binding mode to TwoWay.

```
        SelectedSegment="{Binding SelectedSegment, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: By site rules it is discouraged to put thanks comment, and it is encouraged that you upvote the answer and that you mark it as accepted ;)